# How is the return object in a Python-AWS lambda used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In lambda function templates appear the return object

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": "hello world 2",
        }),
    }
```

I couldn't find any documentation about how this object is used.

- How must be configured?
- What fields are mandatory?
- When and how is it used?  Can be consumed by other services?

Comment: The Lambda is producing JSON.  You need the thing that Is calling it to consume JSON

Comment: How are you intending to call and use your Lambda functions? It is possible that this return message is not required for your use-case.

Comment: There's plenty of concise step-throughs of example scenarios and exciting blogs and articles on AWS, but it's really hard to find reference documentation that properly addresses the options and behaviours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not *need* to return any value, but some calling systems want a response.

For example, if the Lambda function is invoked by API Gateway, it needs to send a response back to the original caller. See: [Handle Lambda errors in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html)

It can also be used to pass back details errors: [AWS Lambda function errors in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-exceptions.html)

Comment: I want to return some value, e.g., the event details, then how can I pass the returned value to other events? e.g., lifecycle configuration in SageMaker? Thank you.

Comment: @Sophia Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old Question. Be sure to include lots of details of what you are wanting to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your suggestion. Please check the link here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76292876/pass-the-event-information-to-boto3-clientsagemaker-start-notebook-instance) as the question I asked. Please let me know if you have any input. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Example:

```
import os
import json
        
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    json_region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({
            "Region ": json_region
        })
    }
```