# pass the event information to boto3.client('sagemaker').start_notebook_instance()

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I am creating a Lambda function to start one SageMaker notebook instance as following:

```
import boto3
import logging
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
    client.start_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName='experiment')
    return 0
```

I want to pass some information from `event` (e.g., S3 bucket name and the file name in the bucket) to the lifecycle configuration (LCC) of the SageMaker notebook instance. From the original post, I know I can not pass through `client.start_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName='experiment')`. My follow-up question is how can I pass `event` information to LCC? I have tried several ways, such as making use of the CloudWatch logs, but none of them works. Can anyone give me a hand? I want to stick with SageMaker notebook instance. Thank you.

Comment: The [`start_notebook_instance()` - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.109/reference/services/sagemaker/client/start_notebook_instance.html) API call does not take any other parameters.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Could you please take a look at the following link? Thank you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76311479/retrieve-log-events-from-a-lambda-function-in-aws

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question, can you not run this api first to create a Lifecycle Config: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/create_notebook_instance_lifecycle_config.html, which you can then attach to the Sagemaker instance you're running. Then for subsequent runs use: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/update_notebook_instance_lifecycle_config.html which takes the dynamic input and updates the config on the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you starting a notebook instance from lambda? If you want schedule jobs you should look at using SageMaker Training or Processing Jobs.

If you want to pass data to the Lifecycle config you could write data to s3 and have code in the lifecycle config read the data from S3.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I definitely can pass the data file path by writing down  it in LCC, however, it is static. I want to make it dynamic since the file name keeps changing.

Comment: For your first question, I want to use Amazon S3 event notification to trigger a Lambda function, which will start a notebook instance. For now, I am not sure SageMaker Training or Processing jobs can achieve this. Thank you for brainstorming with me, otherwise this journey will be too lonely.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution. We can add one tag (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/add_tags.html) to the SageMaker notebook instance (the tag contains the event information), and then pass the tag to the notebook through lifecycle configuration.