# Retrieve log events from a Lambda function in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I want to extract some key event information (such as s3 bucket name, the file name in the s3 bucket, etc.) to a Lifecycle configuration in a SageMaker Notebook instance.

```
{... 'bucket': {'name': 'experiment', 'ownerIdentity': {'principalId': 'xcfdfdfd'}, 'arn': 'arn:aws:s3:::experiment'}, 'object': {'key': 'experiment.csv', 'size': 9927965, 'eTag': 'xxx', 'sequencer': '000dfdfdfd'}}}]}
```

Q1: May I use AWS CLI to get the above?
Q2: How can I pass the latest stream name to the following code if there are multiple streams for the same Lambda function? and how can I get the stream name?

```
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/xxxx --log-stream-name ()
```

Thank you.